# Not finding Xampp in ubuntu software center?

Tags: xampp

Hi all I'm trying to install xampp but I am unable to do it.

I searched many things but wont work for me. I dont know what is happening in my system because even the ubuntu center is unable to find the xampp and lampp both.

What should I do now. How can I install xampp in my system if the terminal is not taking any command.

I am a new in ubuntu using first time.

Any help will be greatfull.

Thanks.

Comment: I would advice to install `tasksel` (sudo apt-get install tasksel) and then install the official supported lamp server by using the command `tasksel` and choosing lamp server. All the official doumentation is for this setup. And with that comes proven security. XAMPP is 3rd party software and it is worse than the official one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont find XAMPP in the software center.

To install it you have to download it from the [official xampp site](http://www.apachefriends.org/download.html), i suggest you choose the PHP 5.5 version.

To install it open the terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and run the following commands:

1. Change the permissions to the installer - `chmod 755 xampp-linux-*-installer.run` (**IMPORTANT** - replace the
       * with either x86 or x64)
2. Run the installer - `sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run` (**IMPORTANT** - replace the
       * with either x86 or x64)
3. To start the program - `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Then open the browser and access `localhost`.

Good luck.