# Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am getting this error while importing the database in mysql, and when I resubmit the same file than I am getting this error

```
Error

SQL query:

-- -- Dumping data for table `adminnotification_inbox` -- INSERT INTO `adminnotification_inbox` (`notification_id`, `severity`, `date_added`, `title`, `description`, `url`, `is_read`, `is_remove`) VALUES (1, 4, '2008-07-25 05:24:17', 'Magento 1.1 Production Version Now Available', 'We are thrilled to announce the availability of the production release of Magento 1.1. Read more about the release in the Magento Blog.', 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/magento-11-is-here-1/', 0, 0), (2, 4, '2008-08-02 05:29:53', 'Updated iPhone Theme is now available', 'Updated iPhone theme for Magento 1.1 is now available on Magento Connect and for upgrade through your Magento Connect Manager.', 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/updated-iphone-theme-for-magento-11-is-now-available/', 0, 0), (3, 3, '2008-08-02 05:40:04', 'Magento version 1.1.2 is now available', 'Magento version 1.1.2 is now available for download and upgrade.', 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/mag[...]

MySQL said: Documentation
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

What should I do now. I already use the time increasing solutions given on the internet but nothing happen. How should I fix this error.

My database size is just only 3 MB. I am using xampp 1.8.3 in ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of XAMPP you may use LAMP(Linux Apache MySQL PHP) mostly. Using LAMP you may also face this problem.

In my case(using Ubuntu 15.10), I had configured/set 
post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, max_execution_time, max_input_time, memory_limit following my needs using php.ini file which is located at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

But still I was faced this proble. Then solved the problem using
 `config.default.php` file, where you can find out like this line below:

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;
```

Make it to

`$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;`

**Note:** You can locate `config.default.php` file via your terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) by this command`locate config.default.php` possible path is `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php`

Hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 4):

let drop it, then in the phpmyadmin config.inc.php you can increase the time out from 300sec to infinity

add this line

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

and:

```
php> php.ini
```

Find:

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M
```

Change to:

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 540
memory_limit = 1000M
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because there's already an existing value of `1` for the column `ID` in which you define it as `PRIMARY KEY` in the table you are inserting (values for the primary keys are unique values).

Try set the column ID as `AUTO_INCREMENT`

I hope this fixes your issue, i noticed you fixed your XAMPP installing issue, please close this open question [**Not finding Xampp in ubuntu software center**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411390/not-finding-xampp-in-ubuntu-software-center)

Answer (score 0):

Go to xampp/phpMyAdmin/libraries/config.default.php 
find `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;` line no 695 and replace `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;`