# In phpmyadmin, importing database shows timeout error in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting an error "script timeout passed..." when trying to import a database.

I have already tried increasing various limits like max_size max_filesize max_time mem_limit in php.ini. But the problem remains.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What have you changed max_execution_time to?  Also, have you restarted php/apache after making the change?

Comment: I have set 600 in max_execution_time. And yes, I have restarted apache after that change. @bc2946088

Comment: Just to be 100% sure the change has taken place, have you checked `<?php phpinfo() ?>` for those values?

Comment: @bc2946088, Tnx much for your effort to help. Though I think i found the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty easy and simple step could be a solution:

**Execution Time Limit** needs to be set as `0` in `config.default.php` file. Which looks like `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;`

Make it to

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

Location of that file supposed to be at `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries`

Ref:[Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411505/script-timeout-passed-if-you-want-to-finish-import-please-resubmit-same-file-a/781195#781195)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I got your ans correct. it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/781389/527764) did not resolve this issue for me, but after some research I found a solution that did; in nginx server default config file after `listen port #`, add these lines:

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 3600; //ms to wait
fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
```